# Stop Servlet Filter after condition satisfies

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have implemented a Filter that will check all the patterns - '/*' using the below code..

Here is my filter code:-

First, it checks for session attribute, if its null it sets a session attribute.

If a user tries to access any URL directly, I check the referrer and redirect to accessblocked.jsp page. This works but it does not redirect to the page..Instead it runs the same check to all URL's within the same page(CSS/image files) and does not load anything..How to stop my filter running once a condition is satisfied?

```
if (session.getAttribute(CHECK_TOKEN) == null) {
            if (referer == null) {
                session.setAttribute(CHECK_TOKEN, CHECK_TOKEN);
            } else if (referer
                    .equals("http://p4-vsa.com/gui/banana/index.html")) {

                httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath()
                        + "/accessblocked.jsp");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure that there's no more code execution after the `httpResponse.sendRedirect` call. You could add a `return` statement after it.

Comment: I added a "return" statement..but it displays a blank screen..I dont see the accessblocked.jsp being displayed

Comment: Are you sure the redirect is being done correctly? Also, are you sure the page you're redirecting is not being captured by your filter as well, thus creating an infinite loop?

Comment: Since the filter operates on '/*' it filters all the pages..Is there a way for me to ignore '/accessblocked.jsp' alone?

Comment: Add an `if` at the beginning to check that the current page is not `accessblocked.jsp`.

Comment: The problem is not for accessblocked.jsp page but other static pages...With this referer- "http://p4-vsa.com/gui/banana/index.html", I get totally 10 files..*.js(hep.js,underscore.js..etc),*.css(bootstrap.css...etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76946/discussion-between-user1050619-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Comment: I would suggest moving all the files (web pages and assets) that need this filter check under a folder rather than being inside root, so you can change your filter to `folder/*` and get rid of all these problems.